# How to duplicate ssh session on tmux

Tags: tmux

I want to duplicate my ssh session again.

For example, my window-name is "user@host'. I wish to press prefix key + S to do 'ssh user@host on a new window'

```
$ tmux bind S confirm-before "neww ssh #W"
```

After try this, it just issue a ssh command without the option 'user@host'
The tmux version is 1.8 on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like this, though it is a little ugly. Place this into your `tmux.conf`:

```
bind S neww "$(ps -ao pid,tty,args | sort | awk '$1 ~ /#{pane_pid}/{VAR=$2} $2 ~ VAR && $3 ~ /ssh/{$1=\"\"; $2=\"\"; print}')"
```

#### Explanation

Creat a binding named `S` and have it open a new window, using the argument as the initial command

```
bind S neww "..."
```

Execute the output of the inner command

```
$(...)
```

List the pid, tty, and command (with arguments) of all processes

```
ps -ao pid,tty,args | ...
```

Sort by pid

```
... | sort | ...
```

Feed output into awk

```
... | awk '...'
```

Find tty of current pane/window, and place it in `VAR` (`#{}` is substituted by tmux)

```
$1 ~ /#{pane_pid}/{VAR=$2}
```

Find process that has the tty we found earlier AND has a command that starts with `ssh`. Note that we are assuming that the pid of the ssh session is greater than the shell it was invoked in. This should be true in most cases.

```
$2 ~ VAR && $3 ~ /ssh/{...}
```

Remove pid, tty, and print the remainder. This will be the ssh command with all arguments and options. This is the command that will get executed in a new window.

```
$1=\"\"; $2=\"\"; print
```

Comment: Use `$1 == ${pan_pid}` is proper then `~`.

Comment: The script you post can not work on my environment. 
I'm trying following but can not work too. How to debug it?

`bind S neww "$(ps -ao ppid,args | awk '$1 == #{pane_pid} && $2 == \"ssh\" {$1=\"\"; $2=\"\"; print; exit 0}')"`